If Dr. Chen is not busy
Why does the speaker use “can” instead of “will be able to” in this sentence?
“If Dr. Chen is not busy, he can meet you tomorrow afternoon.”

What makes you ask so many questions about the differences between “can” and “will be able to”?

Elementary textbooks for learners make the distinction between "can" and "be able" much starker than it actually is, and for 150  years usage manuals distinguished between them: "Don't say can when you mean is able !!!".   Forget all that rubbish. Do it today, if you can.

The speaker can use "can" because he can use "can".  The speaker would have been able to use "is able" because he is able to use "able".  In this case they mean the same.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, can has many different meanings. As you say, it can be used to express ability. Sometimes, more than one meaning is applicable in a particular sentence, but in this sentence I'd go for this meaning:

used to express possibility

Looking at your sentence:

If Dr. Chen is not busy, he can meet you tomorrow afternoon.

So, the sentence means that it will be possible for Dr Chen to meet you tomorrow, if he is not busy.
Imagine that Dr Chen has told his assistant that he doesn't want to see you tomorrow. If he is not busy, he would be able to meet you, but he doesn't want to. "can" indicates that there are no other reasons like this that would  prevent a meeting, so a meeting is possible.

... and before asking further similar questions, please consult the Cambridge Dictionary and try to work out for yourself what the possible meanings are.

Is it common to use “can” to make an appointment or decision based on someone’s current status or schedule?

Yes, it is. You: "When can i see the doctor?" Receptionist: "You can see him on Friday at 2:30, if you are free then."

I agree. In the OP, it sounds like that if Dr. Chen currently doesn’t have any plan on his schedule for tomorrow afternoon, he can meet the listener then. Do you agre?

@ChienTeLu - not just that. Dr Chen's afternoon schedule for tomorrow might be quite full, but he may find that he can make enough time free to see the person.

@MichaelHarvey I would disagree with that. If his availability can only be confirmed tomorrow, then you should use “will be able to” “Can” is for when it’s currently known that he will be free tomorrow afternoon.

@ChienTeLu - no, we may use 'can' for a future hypothetical or at-present-unknown thing. I will tell you tomorrow at 2 PM if I can see you at 3 PM (that same day); if you buy a ticket next Tuesday you can ride the train to London that day or later. Haven't you been told this already, multiple times? Is there a problem?

@ChienTeLu Someone with whom you wish to make an appointment could say "I don't know my schedule yet, but can let you know by end of business today."  It means "Once I find out if I'm free, or not, I will be able to tell you whether the appointment
you'd like to set up is possible."  It is a bit informal. Only the most formal contexts require, or are typically marked by that distinction.

But a speaker could  say "I can let you know later today" and mean "You won't hear from me until later today". They might be very able to tell you  now but might not wish to consult their calendar at that moment, for whatever reason -- they want to go get a cup of coffee, someone's at their office door, they have to go to the rest room, they would like to take a walk, they think you  are being importunate, whatever.
